# When was the last matchup between ranked MAC football teams?

Tags: american-football, collegiate

I'm a Toldeo / Mid-American Conference fan, and just interested in what was the last match up (before December 2022) between two ranked MAC teams?

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, the last time two ranked MAC opponents faced was the [2012 MAC Championship Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_MAC_Championship_Game) between Northern Illinois and Kent State, with Northern Illinois winning the thrilling 2OT game!